# loopback-sdk-angular retrieving all models in a directive

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

It's possible to retrieve a provider based on a model like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LocationCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Location', function($scope, Location) {
    $scope.test = Location.find({
        filter: { }
    });
}]);
```

What I am looking for is a way of accessing to all models from within a controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LocationCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Models', function($scope, Models) {
    $scope.test = Models.Location.find({
        filter: { }
    });
    $scope.test2 = Models.User.find({
        filter: { }
    });
}]);
```

Is there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 1):

No, as each model generated in `lb-services` is a discrete Angular resource. There is nothing built in, but you can probably create your own service that does something similar:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('ModelService, ['Location', 'User', function(Location, User) {
    return {
      Location: Location,
      User: User
    }
  }]);
```